# How to replace words in a string (python)

Tags: python

I need to replace "cry" with "fly" and "want to" with "will" in the string below.

```
message ="I want to cry"
```

I tried this:

```
print(message.replace("cry", "fly")("want to","will"))
```

it doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

You need a separate call to `.replace()` for each replacement.

```
print(message.replace("cry", "fly").replace("want to","will"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary of data that you want to replace

```
message ="I want to cry"

change_word={"cry":"fly","want to":"will"}

for key,value in change_word.items():
    message=message.replace(key,value)
print(message)
```